# Music recognition software API

Tags: open-source, api, music-recognition

I'm looking to implement in a website, or iOS, android app a small music recognition software.

The "problem" lies that I want it to recognise my own music (I'm a composer), based on one or more recordings of the same piece of music.

As such I don't need any kind of a database, or even access to separate websites or data. Just to create my own, small database.

Is there something like this a available?

The pieces will be simple piano tunes, so nothing too complicated in terms of frequencies.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Welcome Nikolas, Sorry no suggestion, just an intrigued party. Hope someone suggests something.

Comment: Thanks Lockszmith.

Let's see if someone knows anything about this particular quiery.

Answer (score 1):

You could submit your own audio fingerprints to [acoustid](https://acoustid.org/) and then query against it.

Note: I've not used it but it seems relevant to your use case (assuming you still need this 2 years later).